# After stripe bitcoin payment not able to see transaction detail of bitcoin payment

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am working on stripe `bitcoin` payment, it is working fine for me, i am able to get its response, but when i go in stripe dashboard page, it doesn't show me that payment in transaction details, can anyone please tell me where can i see my bitcoin payment detail in `stripe dashboard` ?

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
                "amount" => $price,
                "currency" => "usd",
                "source" => $source_id,
            ));
```

Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: Can you see any other payment created by you there? May be you are looking at "Live" mode in the dashboard. Make sure the switch is set to correct environment.

Comment: There is a button "View test data" on left side of the dashboard. check that.